# Accessing a TableRow's style data in a TableView

Tags: javafx, testfx

I'm trying to write some TestFX code that will loop through a TableView component and check the background colour for each row is set correctly.

What I can't work out is how to actually construct the loop to go through the TableRows as opposed to the actual data. I've tried using `sourceTable.getItems()` but that just gives me access to the object containing the data. But I need to go lower down than that and actually examine the background-colour of the CSS tag.

I know that a TableRow has a getStyle function, which will return the data I'm looking for, but I'm at a loss at how to construct the appropriate iteration that will go through each individual row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score -1):

My first thought is to use queryAccessibleAttribute() method.. but unfortunately it is not working working as expected. May be someone can correct me.

```
for (int i=0;i<tableView.getItems().size();i++){
    TableRow row = (TableRow) tableView.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.ROW_AT_INDEX,i);
}
```

So as of now use lookup() for the rendered tablerows.

```
Set<Node> tableRows = tableView.lookupAll("TableRow");
```

Comment: no, that's useless because they are not even available for all items in the table but only for the currently visible items