# How to get the specific cell with (column x and row y) in TableView? javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

given a tableview object
I have got the tableposition for the cell I wanted to get.
I also got the row and column number of the cell I wanted to get.
Let's say it is row 3, column 2, how do I get the cell in row 3 column 2?
I want the cell obj itself, not the value of the cell.

Comment: you don't want to access the cell :) Why would you? Re-think your goal in terms of a (maybe meta-) model instead of cell. Please also see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630608/accessing-a-tablerows-style-data-in-a-tableview)

Comment: I needed to color all the cells that have the specific value. That is why i wanted to get access to the cell. Otherwise how could i do it

Comment: it's the data that drive the view - so you need a custom cell factory which configures itself based on the value

Answer (score -1):

If you are using JavaFX 8u40 or above you can get it by using the AccessibleAttribute.

```
TableCell cell =  (TableCell) tableView.queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.CELL_AT_ROW_COLUMN,rowIndex,columnIndex);
```

Remember you may get null value if the cell is not visible in the tableView viewport.

Comment: no, same comment as in your other answer: there is no way - and for good reason - to reliably access an arbitrary cell

Comment: I did get a null value, how can i fix this? @Sai Dandem

Comment: You need to remember that the internal implementation (VirtualFlow) renders the table cells only which needs to be shown in viewport and it reuses the same cells effectively for the rows/columns that need to be shown. So say among 100 rows in table, if viewport shows only the first 10 rows,. obviously there is no need for JavaFX to render the 100th row unless user scrolls to that row. 
The tweak that I mentioned is a very quick way to get the cell reference in the visible viewport. You need to stick to @kleopatra's  comment to rethink, if it is something you need in broader perspective.